Slow start time (~5s) of netrw on windows
On my work computer (windows 10, managed device from my company) neovim takes 5s-8s to start, when launching it (nvim .), and ~5s of it are from netrw.
I assume this has something to do with cybersecurity settings/software from the managed client (note: I have sort of admin rights on this machine, but cannot change everything).
What can I do, to fix the startup time of netrw, to get back to normal startup times (~1s with my config on my private windows PC)?
Steps I have taken so far:

reinstalled neovim (installed with chocolatey) to NVIM v0.10.1
removed my whole config
added neovim install directory (C:\tools\neovim*), neovim config (AppData\Local\nvim* and AppData\Local\nvim-data*) as well as the directory I start up neovim to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Exclusions\Paths with value 0

Nothing seemed to change the slow startup.
Furthermore, when I directly open a file (nvim file.txt), netrw does not load instantly but the 5s load time appear when I try to browse the directory with :Ex.
Here the output of nvim . --startuptime time.log
--- Startup times for process: Primary/TUI ---

times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.007  000.007: --- NVIM STARTING ---
000.092  000.085: event init
000.284  000.192: early init
024.808  024.524: locale set
024.886  000.078: init first window
036.508  011.622: inits 1
037.078  000.570: window checked
039.783  002.705: parsing arguments
041.866  000.560  000.560: require('vim.shared')
042.781  000.274  000.274: require('vim.inspect')
043.282  000.479  000.479: require('vim._options')
043.291  001.410  000.656: require('vim._editor')
043.297  002.163  000.193: require('vim._init_packages')
043.324  001.379: init lua interpreter
073.981  030.657: --- NVIM STARTED ---

--- Startup times for process: Embedded ---

times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.006  000.006: --- NVIM STARTING ---
000.126  000.120: event init
000.359  000.233: early init
022.512  022.153: locale set
022.584  000.071: init first window
027.168  004.585: inits 1
027.526  000.358: window checked
030.410  002.883: parsing arguments
032.605  000.491  000.491: require('vim.shared')
033.411  000.243  000.243: require('vim.inspect')
033.855  000.423  000.423: require('vim._options')
033.863  001.245  000.578: require('vim._editor')
033.868  001.918  000.182: require('vim._init_packages')
033.893  001.565: init lua interpreter
036.169  002.276: expanding arguments
036.210  000.041: inits 2
037.087  000.877: init highlight
037.095  000.007: waiting for UI
037.360  000.265: done waiting for UI
037.368  000.008: clear screen
038.167  000.070  000.070: require('vim.keymap')
066.862  027.601  027.601: require('vim.termcap')
069.605  002.671  002.671: require('vim.text')
813.926  776.550  746.209: require('vim._defaults')
813.956  000.038: init default mappings & autocommands
820.150  000.314  000.314: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\ftplugin.vim
828.825  000.139  000.139: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\indent.vim
839.746  000.839  000.839: sourcing C:\Users\%myUser%\AppData\Local\nvim\init.lua
841.540  026.293: sourcing vimrc file(s)
851.477  001.190  001.190: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\filetype.lua
913.631  000.560  000.560: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\syntax\synload.vim
924.933  018.989  018.429: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share/nvim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim
984.984  000.680  000.680: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\gzip.vim
1011.753  000.815  000.815: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\pack\dist\opt\matchit\plugin\matchit.vim
1012.561  025.573  024.758: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\matchit.vim
1016.944  000.815  000.815: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\matchparen.vim
1022.572  001.059  001.059: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\netrwPlugin.vim
1032.619  000.118  000.118: sourcing C:\Users\%myUser%\AppData\Local\nvim-data/rplugin.vim
1032.725  008.265  008.147: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\rplugin.vim
1034.728  000.350  000.350: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\shada.vim
1036.886  000.147  000.147: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\spellfile.vim
1039.308  000.473  000.473: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\tarPlugin.vim
1041.771  000.132  000.132: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\tutor.vim
1043.835  000.309  000.309: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\zipPlugin.vim
1046.082  000.648  000.648: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\editorconfig.lua
1048.773  000.792  000.792: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\man.lua
1051.351  000.759  000.759: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\osc52.lua
1053.564  000.551  000.551: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\tohtml.lua
1053.904  151.630: loading rtp plugins
1055.485  001.581: loading packages
1060.869  005.384: loading after plugins
1060.931  000.063: inits 3
1067.906  006.975: reading ShaDa
1068.389  000.483: opening buffers
1068.432  000.043: BufEnter autocommands
1068.439  000.007: editing files in windows
6103.431  5025.186  5025.186: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\autoload\netrw.vim
6113.534  000.216  000.216: sourcing C:\Users\%myUser%\AppData\Local\nvim-data/.netrwhist
6119.418  002.189  002.189: require('vim.filetype')
6133.791  012.039  012.039: require('vim.filetype.detect')
6242.654  001.027  001.027: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\syntax\netrw.vim
6354.914  000.686  000.686: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\syntax\netrw.vim
6463.140  000.713  000.713: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\syntax\netrw.vim
6464.351  353.855: VimEnter autocommands
6464.363  000.012: UIEnter autocommands
6471.567  007.204: before starting main loop
6472.890  001.323: first screen update
6472.905  000.015: --- NVIM STARTED ---

Here the output of nvim test.txt --startuptime time.log
--- Startup times for process: Primary/TUI ---

times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.008  000.008: --- NVIM STARTING ---
000.136  000.128: event init
000.358  000.223: early init
024.465  024.106: locale set
024.554  000.089: init first window
033.849  009.296: inits 1
033.977  000.128: window checked
035.885  001.908: parsing arguments
038.422  000.633  000.633: require('vim.shared')
039.622  000.382  000.382: require('vim.inspect')
040.237  000.583  000.583: require('vim._options')
040.248  001.803  000.839: require('vim._editor')
040.256  002.635  000.199: require('vim._init_packages')
040.302  001.782: init lua interpreter
074.736  034.434: --- NVIM STARTED ---

--- Startup times for process: Embedded ---

times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.008  000.008: --- NVIM STARTING ---
000.113  000.105: event init
000.333  000.220: early init
021.379  021.046: locale set
021.454  000.075: init first window
027.231  005.777: inits 1
027.307  000.076: window checked
029.988  002.680: parsing arguments
032.411  000.528  000.528: require('vim.shared')
033.357  000.299  000.299: require('vim.inspect')
033.889  000.508  000.508: require('vim._options')
033.898  001.472  000.666: require('vim._editor')
033.904  002.185  000.184: require('vim._init_packages')
033.944  001.772: init lua interpreter
035.705  001.760: expanding arguments
035.737  000.033: inits 2
036.587  000.850: init highlight
036.591  000.005: waiting for UI
036.796  000.205: done waiting for UI
036.805  000.009: clear screen
037.331  000.061  000.061: require('vim.keymap')
061.265  023.286  023.286: require('vim.termcap')
063.791  002.457  002.457: require('vim.text')
733.515  696.703  670.899: require('vim._defaults')
733.540  000.033: init default mappings & autocommands
740.387  000.382  000.382: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\ftplugin.vim
747.271  000.125  000.125: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\indent.vim
755.072  000.354  000.354: sourcing C:\Users\%myUser%\AppData\Local\nvim\init.lua
756.449  022.047: sourcing vimrc file(s)
764.097  000.767  000.767: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\filetype.lua
814.782  000.205  000.205: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\syntax\synload.vim
828.287  019.232  019.027: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share/nvim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim
880.440  000.498  000.498: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\gzip.vim
906.068  000.686  000.686: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\pack\dist\opt\matchit\plugin\matchit.vim
906.690  024.439  023.753: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\matchit.vim
910.677  000.394  000.394: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\matchparen.vim
915.467  001.151  001.151: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\netrwPlugin.vim
923.635  000.077  000.077: sourcing C:\Users\%myUser%\AppData\Local\nvim-data/rplugin.vim
923.710  006.493  006.416: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\rplugin.vim
925.119  000.163  000.163: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\shada.vim
926.527  000.092  000.092: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\spellfile.vim
928.268  000.273  000.273: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\tarPlugin.vim
929.974  000.106  000.106: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\tutor.vim
931.788  000.304  000.304: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\zipPlugin.vim
933.753  000.469  000.469: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\editorconfig.lua
935.722  000.461  000.461: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\man.lua
937.717  000.459  000.459: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\osc52.lua
939.618  000.432  000.432: sourcing C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\plugin\tohtml.lua
939.901  127.719: loading rtp plugins
941.735  001.833: loading packages
946.868  005.133: loading after plugins
946.931  000.063: inits 3
954.506  007.575: reading ShaDa
965.932  002.414  002.414: require('vim.filetype')
973.383  006.301  006.301: require('vim.filetype.detect')
979.967  000.088  000.088: require('vim.F')
985.594  005.598  005.598: require('editorconfig')
986.098  000.489  000.489: require('vim.fs')
994.734  025.336: opening buffers
994.791  000.057: BufEnter autocommands
994.805  000.015: editing files in windows
995.288  000.482: VimEnter autocommands
995.294  000.007: UIEnter autocommands
1001.049  005.755: before starting main loop
1001.449  000.399: first screen update
1001.455  000.006: --- NVIM STARTED ---


I suppose it could be a bug in Neovim? First thing I'd check is to make sure the netrw scripts are up-to-date; I think they've seen some recent bugfixes.

Thanks for your reply, I have now checked and seen that there are a few commits on neovims master branch into netrw.vim and others. I removed my neovim and downloaded the latest version as portable version, and still have the same issue sadly.

FWIW on Vim 9.1.516, vim . is instantaneous for me.

Yes, nvim . is also ~250ms (~instantaneous) for me on my private machine for example.
I assume my problem comes from company IT security programs running, and interfering with netrw loading, and I am hoping to find some help how to debug this further.
